# Using Countif with two parameters

Tags: excel

I wish to count the number of dates in a given column.  The column has three possible values for a cell.  A cell can be blank, have an "x", or have a date.  I don't care what the actual date is, I just want to count the number of cells that have a date in them.

Comment: Have you tried `COUNTIFS()`?

Comment: Dates are simply formatted numbers in Excel so you can use `COUNT` to count numbers, which won't count blanks or "x"s e.g. `=COUNT(A:A)`

Comment: @barryhoudini Sorry, didn't see your comment and posted an exact same answer, hope that is OK, happy to delete if not.

Comment: @zx8754 - no problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS()

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">=" & DATE(1900,1,1),A:A,"<=" & DATE(2045,12,31))
```

You can bracket the dates to what ever you want.

[image]

---

OR

You can do the negative.

If you are possitive the only three values possible are blank,`x`, and a date then:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<>",A:A,"<>x")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `COUNT`, it counts only if the cell value is numeric. The dates are internally numeric.

```
=COUNT(A:A)
```

[image]